# get value of select box on the selection of category of second select box

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I need select box to load values on page load.

I have two select boxes if i select one option from first select box.
than other select box loads the values from database but i need the other one select box value on page load which first select box select the category the second depend on that select box.

only the first selection of first select box should load the second select box value on page load not on my function of onChange().

```
<select name="delclassselected" id="delclassselected" onChange="selectSubject()" >
<?php echo($showclasssvalue); ?>
</select>
```

Comment: so what did you try ? add some code

Comment: Here is an example: http://www.yourinspirationweb.com/en/how-to-create-chained-select-with-php-and-jquery/

Comment: To use the `onchange` event-handler (and please don't use in-line JavaScript event-handling), you'll need to use JavaScript; and for us to help you with JavaScript we'd really need to see some actual HTML, and how the choices in the first `select` element relate to the second.

Comment: @DavidThomas Sorry, why not use in-line JavaScript? :)

Comment: Why is this tagged `jQuery`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Perhaps he is using jQuery for the `selectSubject()`?